# Java comparacion String o Arraylist

Tags: java

no se como realizar un codigo en java.
Tengo un String llamando Poderes donde estan dentro : Arco,Inteligencia,fuerza y pocima.
Otro String llamado Miguel con : inteligencia,paciencia.
Y por ultimo uno llamado Agus con : pocima,inteligencia y invisibilidad.

Tengo que comparar el primer string sobre los otros dos y debe salir esto por pantalla:

Arco-Apariciones : 0,
Fuerza-Apariciones : 0,
Inteligencia-Apariciones : 2,
Pocima-Apariciones : 1

Comment: buenas, pon el código que llevas hecho hasta ahora al menos para que te podamos ayudar

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> Miguel = new ArrayList<String>();
Miguel.add("inteligencia");
Miguel.add("paciencia");
ArrayList<String> Agus= new ArrayList<String>();
Agus.add("inteligencia");
Agus.add("paciencia");
int contadorInteligencia = 0;

contadorInteligencia  += Collections.frequency(Agus, "inteligencia");
contadorInteligencia  += Collections.frequency(Miguel, "inteligencia");
System.out.println("Apariciones inteligencia: " + contadorInteligencia );
```

Comment: Me saca por pantalla inteligencia: 0. Seria posible comparar los 3 arraylist a la vez? El ejercicio me pide que lo haga con arraylist o String

Comment: Con arraylist es mucho mas sencillo, edito mi respuesta para ello

Comment: @PabloLozano respuesta actualizada

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, eres un crack!!!!!!!

Comment: @PabloLozano si es lo que buscabas y te funciona acepta la pregunta como solución para posible gente que vaya buscando respuesta, no es nada para eso estamos.

Comment: Deberías explicar algo de lo que has hecho, una respuesta que sólo tiene código es difícil de entender o reaprovechar, por lo que se considera de *mala calidad* (nota: no soy el OP, somos tocayos)